# UITextField touch events don`t work in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uialertview

I have a UITextField, in which textfield action is not working when UITextField is a subview of UIScrollView.

Other wise , it is working fine , 
Here is my code .. Please Help ?

I am using this code because i need to fire a UIDatePicker Right after alertview Buttons click.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

[self.view addSubview:scroll];

date = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 150, 150, 50)];
date.placeholder = @"Date";
date.delegate = self;
[date addTarget:self action:@selector(dateClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[scroll addSubview:date];
 }

  - (void)dateClicked:(id)sender
    {
    NSLog(@"CLICKED");
     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Choose Date Format" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dd/MM/YYYY" otherButtonTitles:@"MM/dd/YYYY", nil];
     [alertView show];
      }
```

Comment: use UIControlEventEditingDidBegin instead UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Comment: Its working , But i want to open a uipicker on the alertView Button CLick which update the textfield text , If i use UIControlEventEditingDidBegin then after updating text , the alertview will get opened again @Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set `UIButton` same frame as `UITextField` and set `UIButton`  `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event and update `UITextField` value.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    date = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 150, 150, 50)];
    date.placeholder = @"Date";
    UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 150, 150, 50)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(dateClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scroll addSubview:date];
    [scroll addSubview:btn];
}
- (void)dateClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CLICKED");
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Choose Date Format" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dd/MM/YYYY" otherButtonTitles:@"MM/dd/YYYY", nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: Its working , But i want to open a uipicker on the alertView Button CLick which update the textfield text , If i use UIControlEventEditingDidBegin then after updating text , the alertview will get opened again @Dharmesh

Answer (score 1):

i have created simple Example as per your requirement look at this:

in .h file

```
 UITextField *date;
 NSMutableArray *arrData;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    date = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 150, 150, 50)];
    date.placeholder = @"Date";
    date.delegate = self;
    [date addTarget:self action:@selector(dateClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
    [scroll addSubview:date];

    arrData = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         [arrData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Object - %d",i]]
    }
}

- (void)dateClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CLICKED");
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Choose Date Format" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dd/MM/YYYY" otherButtonTitles:@"MM/dd/YYYY", nil];
    [alertView show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 200, 150, 150)];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 5;
}
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return arrData[row];
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    date.text = arrData[row];
    [pickerView removeFromSuperview];
}
```